# Unexpected behaviour display: block;

Tags: php, html, css, symfony, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation 5

layout.html.twig:

```
...
            {% block top %}

                <div class="row" style="max-width: none !important;">
                    <nav class="top-bar">

                        <a href="#" style="margin-left: 40px">
                            {% image 'bundles/delivveweb/images/Logo_Delivve.png' %}
                            <img src="{{ asset_url }}">
                            {% endimage %}
                        </a>

                        <section class="right top-bar-section top-bar-section-layout">
                            <!-- Right Nav Section -->
                            <ul>
                                <li><a class="right-off-canvas-toggle" href="#">NOTIFICAÇÕES</a></li>
                                <li><a class="right-off-canvas-toggle" href="#">PERFIL</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </section>
                    </nav>
                </div>

                <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu box-shadow">
                    <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                        <li><label>PERFIL</label></li>
                        <li><a href="#">EDITAR PERFIL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ALTERAR SENHA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">LOGOFF</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>

            {% endblock %}
...
```

what happens is that when I resize the screen to the phone size o meno disappears, I realized that this is because the `<a class="right-off-canvas-toggle" href="#">` has a `display: block`, has a solution that would use something in css:

```
@media (max-width: 40em) {
    .top-bar-section ul li > a {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

But if possible would like another solution, because for this visual effect:

```
.top-bar-section-layout li a:not(.button):hover {
    background-image: url('../images/laranja_active_top_full.png') !important;
}
```

accurate `display: block` is not the image undergoes resizing and is not the size of the whole menu bar

thanks!!!

Comment: I don't see the *right-off-canvas-toggle* in your code, where is it?, do you have a jsbin or something with the live code for debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<nav class="top-bar top-bar-layout" data-topbar role="navigation">

<ul class="title-area">
    <a href="{{ path('default_target') }}" style="margin-left: 40px">
        {% image 'bundles/delivveweb/images/Delivve_logo.png' %}
        <img src="{{ asset_url }}" style=" margin-top: 5px; height: 45px">
        {% endimage %}
    </a>
    <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
</ul>

<section class="top-bar-section top-bar-section-layout">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
        <li>
            <a id="view_central" href="{{ path('notifications') }}#home">
                {% image 'bundles/delivveweb/images/icon_central.png' %}
                <img id="central" src="{{ asset_url }}">
                {% endimage %}
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a id="view_notification">
                {% image 'bundles/delivveweb/images/icon_alerta.png' %}
                <img id="alert_notification" src="{{ asset_url }}">
                {% endimage %}
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown scroll-menu">
                {% include 'DelivveWebBundle:Notification:show_all.html.twig' with {'notifications': notifications, 'field': "li"} %}
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle" href="{{ path('edit_user', {'realname': owner.realname} ) }}">
                <img src="{{ asset(owner.getPictureWeb()) }}" class="img-perfil-mini active-img">
                <img src="{{ asset(owner.getPictureUrl()) }}" class="img-perfil-mini hidden-img">
                {% image 'bundles/delivveweb/images/icon_perfil.png' %}
                <img src="{{ asset_url }}" class="img-perfil-mini hidden-img"/>
                {% endimage %}
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown scroll-menu">
                <li><a href="{{ logout_path('web') }}">LOGOFF</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>

</nav>
```

I ended up giving up on solving keep the buttons on the responsive menu. Now when the screen is the tamnho phone it puts the 3 dash horizontally, thanks to the passage `<li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"> <a href="#"> <span> </span> </a> </li>`